# Why has Google indexed the same page twice for my site?

Tags: google, wordpress, search-engine-indexing

Google has indexed the same page twice For my website. I am not able to figure out the solution for this issue. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

I am attaching screenshots below for the reference.
[image]

[image]

Comment: breadcrumbs are different: tech vs. technology. urls seem to be different too. check everything, what wrote Theo van der Zee in his answer and, additionally, canonical setup.

Comment: It is unusual for Google to index a page twice, even if you do have the same content on different URLs.   Google is usually very good at detecting duplicate pages.  When it finds duplicates it will usually ignore one and choose the other to get indexed.

Answer (score 3):

When you click on the pages, are the URLs identical? I'm guessing their aren't, and that is caused by some form of technical issue such as those outlined above.

For instance, check for:

- https vs. http
- with trailing / vs without trailing /
- with index.php vs. without index.php?